# Get Latest Vimeo Portfolio Video

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, vimeo, vimeo-api

I have a client that wants to pull the latest video in a specific Vimeo Portfolio. I can pull in the latest video on the entire account using JS like so:

http://codepen.io/buschschwick/pen/pgrmvg

```
    var vimeoUserName = 'yellowboxfilms';

    // Tell Vimeo what function to call
    var videoCallback = 'latestVideo';
    var oEmbedCallback = 'embedVideo';

    // Set up the URLs
    var videosUrl = 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/' + vimeoUserName + '/videos.json?callback=' + videoCallback;
    var oEmbedUrl = 'http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json';

    // This function puts the video on the page
    function embedVideo(video) {
        videoEmbedCode = video.html;
        document.getElementById('embed').innerHTML = unescape(video.html);
    }

    // This function uses oEmbed to get the last clip
    function latestVideo(videos) {
        var videoUrl = videos[0].url;

        // Get the oEmbed stuff
        loadScript(oEmbedUrl + '?url=' + encodeURIComponent(videoUrl) + '&callback=' + oEmbedCallback);
    }

    // This function loads the data from Vimeo
    function loadScript(url) {
        var js = document.createElement('script');
        js.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        js.setAttribute('src', url);
        document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(js);
    }

    // Call our init function when the page loads
    window.onload = function() {
        loadScript(videosUrl);
    };
```

But I want to pull a latest in a portfolio. I found the API Call, but I get an authorization error.

http://codepen.io/buschschwick/pen/jWLoWb

```
var latestVideo = function() {
  var vimeoAPI = 'https://api.vimeo.com/users/414104/portfolios';
  $.getJSON(vimeoAPI).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
};

latestVideo();
```

I think it might need an oAuth token or something like that, but trying to find out how to pass that got me no where and I feel the Vimeo API Docs aren't helping either. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are Vimeo's authentication docs: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication

You can generate a single token on your app page, or you can generate the token on a server.

Vimeo's token generation does not yet support client side authorization, so know that if you share the token in the client, anyone can take that token and make API calls.

You can reduce the risk by requesting read-only scopes, but that token will still have access to private data.

Comment: I guess where I am getting hung up is HOW to get access. Do I need to use a library like https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php to setup the API initially?

Comment: That library is definitely a good start! It does a lot of the work for you, but isn't necessary